# Getting rid of duplicates in a joined SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am wanting to know if there is any way to get rid of the duplicate row information that is it creating in order to fill space in the results when there are 2 items in one table, but only 1 in the other. I've tried different joins and a group by and neither of those worked. I'm thinking I need someone sort of nested subquery or a limit or rownum = 1 condition somewhere. Thank you for any provided help.

My code:

```
select distinct
    Driver_Extra_Pay.Order_ID as 'Order',
    Deduct_Code_ID as 'D/E Code',
    Short_Desc as 'Pay Description',
    Driver_Extra_Pay.Amount as 'Pay Amount',
    Driver_Extra_Pay.Amount_D as 'Pay Date',
    Other_Charge.Descr as 'Charge Description',
    Other_Charge.Amount as 'Charge Amount',
    Other_Charge.Amount_D as 'Charge Date'

from
    Driver_Extra_Pay
inner join
    Other_Charge on Other_Charge.Order_ID = Driver_Extra_Pay.Order_ID

where Driver_Extra_Pay.Amount_D between '03/29/2016' and '03/30/2016'

order by Driver_Extra_Pay.Order_ID
```

This is the result I get. It's written this way to use as a comparison tool but it's giving double "Lumper" entries when there is only 1. Seems like it's just duplicating it to have something fill that blank space.

[image]

I would like for it to look like this on output instead, but I don't know the coding to make it happen.

[image]

Comment: They're not duplicates. They have different charge information.

Comment: No, SQL doesn't work like that. It doesn't "mask out" values in columns on some rows when other rows have the same values in those columns. Each row has its own set of values. Can we get a result like that returned, yes we could do that. But the syntax required to do that is awkward, and flies in the face of SQL conventions. Don't do it in the SQL, do it in the client.

Comment: If you want to hide duplicates of certain columns, do that in the application code that processes the results. It can check whether those columns are the same as the previous row, and leave them blank.

Comment: This isn't something that you should be doing from the data layer.  If you want to display the results like that, it should be handled on the presentation layer.

Comment: On an entirely different note.... the values compared to the `Amount_D` column appear to be character strings in a non-canonical format. Consider the result when we request `Amount_D between '12/30/2016' and '01/02/2017'`. If we are expecting "date" comparisons, if the column is DATE datatype, we should be using DATE literals, e,g ... `'2016-03-29'`, not `'03/29/2016'`.

Comment: Ok I guess I will see what can be done on the Java interface side. Thanks.

Comment: As it stands I cannot tweak anything on the presentation side because we are not using a SSRS or other reporting software but rather a specific proprietary interface that will not allow me to mess with its Java source coding in how it displays reports from queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you want to display data is not going to work in SQl. You can display it that way if you want in the presentation layer. But since other charges do not seems to directly relate to Driver Extra pay, perhaps what you really need to get the proper data is a UNION ALL. This would return all the the charges for that date range in both tables making it easier to later sum them if need be.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
    (select distinct
        Driver_Extra_Pay.Order_ID as 'Order',
        Deduct_Code_ID as 'D/E Code',
        Short_Desc as 'Description',
        Driver_Extra_Pay.Amount as 'Amount',
        Driver_Extra_Pay.Amount_D as 'Date'
    from
        Driver_Extra_Pay
    where Driver_Extra_Pay.Amount_D between '03/29/2016' and '03/30/2016'
    UNION ALL
    select distinct
       Other_Charge.Order_ID as 'Order',
       'Other' as 'D/E Code',
       Other_Charge.Descr ,
       Other_Charge.Amount,
       Other_Charge.Amount_D,
    from
        Other_Charge 
    where  Other_Charge .Amount_D between '03/29/2016' and '03/30/2016') a
    order by [Order]
```

This query would report other charges that do not have a corresponding Driver Extra Pay record (which your current query would not.) If you need that, then try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(select distinct
    Driver_Extra_Pay.Order_ID as 'Order',
    Deduct_Code_ID as 'D/E Code',
    Short_Desc as 'Description',
    Driver_Extra_Pay.Amount as 'Amount',
    Driver_Extra_Pay.Amount_D as 'Date'
from
    Driver_Extra_Pay
where Driver_Extra_Pay.Amount_D between '03/29/2016' and '03/30/2016'
UNION ALL
select distinct
   Other_Charge.Order_ID as 'Order',
   'Other' as 'D/E Code',
   Other_Charge.Descr ,
   Other_Charge.Amount,
   Other_Charge.Amount_D,
from
    Driver_Extra_Pay
inner join
    Other_Charge on Other_Charge.Order_ID = Driver_Extra_Pay.Order_ID
where Driver_Extra_Pay.Amount_D between '03/29/2016' and '03/30/2016') a
order by [Order]
```

Comment: The 2nd option kind of does what I want, but there's no way to tell based on the way the rows are displayed what information is from what table. This query is being used explicitly to square up values between 2 tables and compare them to see if they match up.

Comment: Sure you can, 'D/E Code' telss which is from which table. The value id Other if it came from Other_charge. The value is whatever is stored in Driver extra Pay  for those from teh Driver Extra Pay table.

Comment: Your right I could add another column to them to identify them. Your d/e code as other is a good idea but i may actually need that pulled from the other table. Thanks.